# google sheets formula to add commas to a number

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

### Objective

To get the values returned from the below formula to display with commas i.e. 429489281 would become 429,489,281. I've been able to find was how to format the cell if this was a standard number but I haven't been able to find something to say how this could be done within a formula itself. Can someone confirm if there is a simple approach to do this so my values take the "number" format, without decimals?

### Cells

```
B6 = 429489281
B17 = 605036489
```

### Formula

```
="The total number of delivery in Q1 was "&B6&" compared to "&B17&" in Q4 "&"["&ROUND(((B6-B17)/B17)*100)&"%]."
```

### Current Output

The total number of impressions tracked in Q1 was 429489281 compared to 605036489 in Q4 [-29%].

### Desired Output

The total number of impressions tracked in Q4 was 429,489,281 compared to 605,036,489 in Q4 [-29%].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In excel you would use `TEXT` formula:

```
...." & TEXT(B6,"#,0") & " compared to " & TEXT(B7, "#,0") & " in Q4....
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `TEXT` to format the number
`="The total number of delivery in Q1 was "&TEXT(B6,"#,0")&" compared to "&TEXT(B17,"#,0")&" in Q4 "&"["&ROUND(((B6-B17)/B17)*100)&"%]."`